# Is there a way to set defaults for generate scripts in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-2008

Most of the time when I generate script in SSMS, I have to changed the exact same number of settings in the [Generate and Publish Scripts wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx). Is there a way to set the defaults in this wizard (particularly in the [Advanced Scripting Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx#AdvScriptOpt) dialog?

If not, does anyone have any interesting ways of facilitating this need?

Comment: `Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting`?

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. This gets me half way there...one I am not seeing is where to set the default for 'Script DROP and CREATE' to 'Script DROP and CREATE'. It is weird that they have some but not all of the settings in the options.

Comment: I haven't actually tested that these settings affect the wizard defaults either. Maybe they just affect what happens when you generate scripts by right clicking individual objects.

Comment: I think your first comment is good enough for an answer. Will you add it as one so I can mark it as my answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can answer your own as well.  But, in absence of that:

```
Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting?
```